# lex and yacc — combine two lexers and one yacc

Tags: c, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I have two `lex` files with functions `xxlex()` and `yylex()` and I have one `yacc` grammar file. I wanted on a grammatical rule to always invoke `xxlex()`.  But `xxlex()` is only called once, and I want it to be invoked always. How do I do it?

Comment: I think sharing your codes would be a good start.

Comment: I think sharing your *actual problem* would be a good idea. Why do you need two lexers? Are there two input sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Yacc grammars call `yylex()` to obtain new tokens.

If you want to call `xxlex()` some of the time, then you arrange to call it from `yylex()` at the appropriate times.

If you want `xxlex()` to be called every time, then either rename it `yylex()` and rename the original `xxlex()` to `zzlex()`, or use `bison -p xx` so that everything (including the parser function) starts with `xx` instead of `yy`.  (The same flag, `-p`, also works with POSIX-compliant [`yacc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/yacc.html).  The `flex` program takes `-P xx` to generate symbols all starting with `xx` instead of `yy`; POSIX `lex` does not have an option to do so, but I've seen many a `makefile` with a `sed` script that edits the source generated by `lex` to change the prefix from `yy` to some other letters such as `xx`.)